# How do I parse HTML-like with errors?

Tags: python, html, parsing

I have data that looks like it is part of an HTML document. However there are some bugs in it like

```
<td class= foo"bar">
```

on which all the parsers I tried (lxml, xml.etree) fail with an error.

Since I don't actually care about this specific part of the document I am looking for a more robust parser.

Something where I can allow errors in specific subtrees to be ignored and maybe just not insert the nodes or something that will only lazily parse the parts of the tree I am traversing for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using XML parsers. XML is a strict language, while the HTML standard requires parsers to be tolerant of errors.

Use a compliant HTML parser like [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html), or [`html5lib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html5lib), or the wrapper library [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (which [uses either of the previous](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) with a cleaner API). `html5lib` is slower but closely mimics how a modern browser would treat errors.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is also really convenient for navigating the result!

Answer (score 1):

Use lxml:

Create a HTML parser with the `recover` set to True:

```
parser = etree.HTMLParser(recover=True)
tree   = etree.parse(StringIO(broken_html), parser)
```

See the tutorial [Parsing XML and HTML with lxml](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsing-html).